# My Rails rake test is getting killed ( timing out ) because of what I think ( ! ) is because of a lazy build method I wrote

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

Would anyone here happen to know if the following code is capable of causing an awful drain on the processor behind running `rake test` ?

```
  def calc_yesterday_count
    self.jobs.select{|a| a.completed_on > Time.zone.now.yesterday.beginning_of_day && a.completed_on < Time.zone.now.yesterday.end_of_day if a.completed_on != nil}.length
  end

  def calc_yesterday_sum
    self.jobs.select{|a| a.completed_on > Time.zone.now.yesterday.beginning_of_day && a.completed_on < Time.zone.now.yesterday.end_of_day if a.completed_on != nil}.map(&:total).sum
  end

  def calc_today_count
    self.jobs.select{|a| a.completed_on > Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day && a.completed_on < Time.zone.now.end_of_day if a.completed_on != nil}.length
  end

  def calc_today_sum
    self.jobs.select{|a| a.completed_on > Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day && a.completed_on < Time.zone.now.end_of_day if a.completed_on != nil}.map(&:total).sum
  end

  def calc_week_count
    self.jobs.select{|a| a.completed_on > Time.zone.now.beginning_of_week && a.completed_on < Time.zone.now.end_of_week if a.completed_on != nil}.length
  end

  def calc_week_sum
    self.jobs.select{|a| a.completed_on > Time.zone.now.beginning_of_week && a.completed_on < Time.zone.now.end_of_week if a.completed_on != nil}.map(&:total).sum
  end

  def calc_month_count
    self.jobs.select{|a| a.completed_on > Time.zone.now.beginning_of_month && a.completed_on < Time.zone.now.end_of_month if a.completed_on != nil}.length
  end

  def calc_month_sum
    self.jobs.select{|a| a.completed_on > Time.zone.now.beginning_of_month && a.completed_on < Time.zone.now.end_of_month if a.completed_on != nil}.map(&:total).sum
  end

  def calc_year_count
    self.jobs.select{|a| a.completed_on > Time.zone.now.beginning_of_year && a.completed_on < Time.zone.now.end_of_year if a.completed_on != nil}.length
  end

  def calc_year_sum
    self.jobs.select{|a| a.completed_on > Time.zone.now.beginning_of_year && a.completed_on < Time.zone.now.end_of_year if a.completed_on != nil}.map(&:total).sum
  end

  def calc_open_estimates_sum
    self.jobs.uncompleted.select{|a|a.which != 'job'}.map(&:total).sum
  end

  def calc_jobs_in_progress_sum
    self.jobs.non_estimate.uncompleted.select{|a| a.scheduled_on < Time.zone.now if a.scheduled_on != nil}.map(&:total).sum
  end

alias :account_stats_method :account_stats


    #lazy build account stats
def build_account_stats
  @estimates_in_progress = self.jobs.completed.select{|a|a.which != 'job'}.map(&:total).sum
  @jobs_in_progress      = self.jobs.non_estimate.uncompleted.select{|a| a.scheduled_on < Time.zone.now if a.scheduled_on != nil}.map(&:total).sum
  @account_stats = {
    :account_id         => self.id,
    :yesterday_count    => self.calc_yesterday_count,
    :yesterday_total    => self.calc_yesterday_sum,
    :today_count        => self.calc_today_count,
    :today_total        => self.calc_today_sum,
    :week_count         => self.calc_week_count,
    :week_total         => self.calc_week_sum,
    :month_count        => self.calc_month_count,
    :month_total        => self.calc_month_sum,
    :year_count         => self.calc_year_count,
    :year_total         => self.calc_year_sum
  }
  self.create_account_stats(@account_stats)
end

def account_stats
  if account_stats_method.nil?
    build_account_stats
  else
    account_stats_method
  end
end
```

Comment: How are we supposed to know what any of those calc_* methods do?

Comment: Oops, sorry bout that Beerlington. I updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still a little hard to see what is going on, but I'm assuming self.jobs is based on an ActiveRecord association. When you use `self.jobs.select { ... }` it's loading all the jobs from the database and then iterating over all of them to figure out which ones to pull out. You'd be better off using database queries there to select the records you want. Changing `select` to `where` should be the right direction to go, assuming you're using Rails 3. if you're on Rails 2, you will need to change this to `:conditions`.

```
self.jobs.where('completed_on > ? AND completed_on < ? AND completed_on IS NOT NULL' , Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day, Time.zone.now.end_of_day).map(&:total).sum
```

Comment: I will give this a go. Thanks Beer. :D Hope the weather in VT is treating you right.